# React - Context structure issue

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In short, I got a global context at the root of the project - which is provided to the child components. One of the child components need to be a context provider itself, but its children needs to access both contexts.

Though I could just append the fields to the first context (e.g. deconstructing context and adding more to child object), but I couldn't figure out how.

Then I created another context (child context) and wrapped the child, but when I access it, only the child context is available, not the global.

Example.

```js
// DrawerContext Context component
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
const DrawerContext = createContext()
export default DrawerContext

// GlobalContext Context component
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
const GlobalContext = createContext()
export default GlobalContext

---

// So root has ..
 <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ 
              someValue: someValue }}>
              <Child />
</GlobalContext.Provider>

// Child has ...

<DrawerContext.Provider value={{
        anotherValue: anotherValue
        }}>
          <subChild />
</DrawerContext.Provider>

// Subchild ...
const drawerContext = useContext(DrawerContext) // This has values
const context = useContext(GlobalContext) // This is undefined .. :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologize, the way I was testing omitted the actual GlobalContext - that was the reason it was undefined.

The code example above works just fine.